# Looking for established survey question to rate search function

Tags: search, surveys

Does someone has a link or ressource for a established/ tested/ understandable question asking for the "search function" of a ecommerce website?

I prefer a german version, but english is fine as well.

Edit: I am looking for question about the search function in my next survey. Something like "How good was the search result?" or "Did the search help to find your products?". Is there an established question for this?

Comment: Are you asking for research about Search?

Comment: No, I am looking for a question about search functionality for my survey

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a way to assess the Search on an e-commerce website, I think. And in German.

These resources may help, *aber alles ist in Englisch geschrieben*:

- The Nielsen Norman group has lots of articles about search, and they back up their work with research. [Have a look](http://www.nngroup.com/search/?q=search). It's in English.
- User Interface EWngineering has an [article about faceted search](https://www.uie.com/articles/faceted_search/) that's more specific to e-commerce. And UIE has [lots of other material](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&sitesearch=uie.com&q=search&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=BFunVZXdE4K6eLfhi7AN), as well. Also in English.

I myself have spent time [looking at the Search logs](http://www.uie.com/articles/time_search/), to see how well Search is performing for customers seeking to sign up for courses. I learned more from looking at the data than by asking users.

If, on the other hand, you're asking for a questionnaire that you can administer to site visitors to assess the search, I don't have any suggestions.

I hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks JeromeR but I am looking for a question to ask about it not resources. I want to ask my users how they percieve the search functionality. I made my question more clear.

Comment: Glad you were able to clarify the question.